# Regular Expression for Digits and Special Characters - C#

Tags: c#, regex, string

I use `Html-Agility-Pack` to extract information from some websites. In the process I get data in the form of `string` and I use that data in my program.

Sometimes the data I get includes multiple details in the single `string`. As the name of this Movie **"Dog Eats Dog (2012) (2012)"**. The name should have been **"Dog Eats Dog (2012)"** rather than the first one.

Above is the one example from many. In order to correct the issue I tried to use `string.Distinct()` method but it would remove all the duplicate characters in the `string` as in above example it would return **"Dog Eats (2012)"**. Now it solved my initial problem by removing the 2nd **(2012)** but created a new one by changing the actual title.

I thought my problem could be solved with `Regex` but I have no idea as to how I can use it here. As far as I know if I use `Regex` it would tell me that there are duplicate items in the `string` according to the defined `Regex` code.

But how do I remove it? There can be a `string` like "Meme 2013 (2013) (2013)".
Now the actual title is "Meme 2013" with year (2013) and the duplicate year (2013). Even if I get a `bool` value indicating that the `string` has duplicate year, I cant think of any method to actually remove the duplicate `substring`.

The duplicate year always comes in the end of the `string`. So what should be the `Regex` that I would use to determine that the string actually has two years in it, like (2012) (2012)?

If I can correctly identify the `string` contains duplicate maybe I can use `string.LastIndexOf()` to try and remove the duplicate part. If there is any better way to do it please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right regex is `"( \(\d{4}\))\1+"`.

```
string pattern = @"( \(\d{4}\))\1+";
new Regex(pattern).Replace(s, "$1");
```

Example here : https://repl.it/Evcy/2

Explanation:
Capture one " (dddd)" block, and remove all following identical ones.
`( \(\d{4}\))` does the capture, `\1+` finds any non empty sequence of that captured block

Finally, replace the initial block and its copies by the initial block alone.

Comment: your answer worked for some entries but not for all but the below answer is working fine for everything. Please update your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This regex will allow for any pattern of whitespace, even none, as in `(2013)(2013)`

```
`@"(\(\d{4}\))(?:\s*\1)+"`
```

I have a demo of it [here](http://rextester.com/IXMCVA40382)